# Is there possibility to get releases with pyGithub

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I havent used PyGithub yet but I am just curious if there is any possibility to get a list of releases from a repository (e.g. `https://github.com/{username}/{repo-name}/releases`). I can not see any information about that in documentation [here](http://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis.html).

Comment: If you have no specific requirements for PyGithub I can strongly recommend `github3.py`, which does support this API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is a bit old but nobody seems to have answered it in the way the OP asked.

PyGithub does have a way to return releases of a repo, here is a working example:

```py
from github import Github

G = Github('')  # Put your GitHub token here
repo = G.get_repo('justintime50/github-archive')
releases = repo.get_releases()

for release in releases:
    print(release.title)
```

The above will return the following:

```sh
v4.3.0
v4.2.2
v4.2.1
v4.2.0
v4.1.1
...
```

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of releases from a GitHub repo by making a GET request to

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}/releases
```

Eg

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/releases'
response = requests.get(url)

# Raise an exception if the API call fails.
response.raise_for_status()

data = response.json()
```

Also its worth noting you should be making authenticated requests otherwise you'll hit GitHubs API rate limiting pretty quickly and just get back 403s.

Comment: thanks for answering but i was thinking about using just PyGithub to maintain my requirements to github but i see that i will need to create separate function for this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to make some notification about new releases of most interesting repositories for me which will be loaded from `yaml` or similar.

Comment: Are these repos you own? If so you could set up a webhook and listen for a release event https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#releaseevent

Comment: No, they are not mine.

Comment: I'm still a little unsure as to what you need to do. Do you want to know when packages are being released so you can update your projects third party requirements?

Comment: So you could then just define this in your requirements.txt file. For example

```
Django
djangorestframework
```

and then run 

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

This would install the latest version of each package.

You can also define versions in your requirements file like so

`Django==1.10.3`

Comment: i see that I misunderstood your previous comment. I don't mean python requirements but just other requirements like for infrastructure components like `docker`, `kubernetes`, `prometheus` and so on

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for PyGithub doesn't mention it, but I believe that `pygithub-1.29` (the latest published on PyPi as of today) does in fact contain this API: [`Repository.py`](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/blob/v1.29/github/Repository.py#L2056) for the `v1.29` tag contains a `get_releases()` function.

There is also an [open, unmerged pull request](https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/pull/361) that appears to fill out this API to include assets, too.